# cannot upgrade or install or remove successfully

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates

```
sudo apt-get -f install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done

The following additional packages will be installed:
 libx265-102

The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libx265-102

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.

11 not fully installed or removed.

Need to get 0 B/1,001 kB of archives.

After this operation, 11.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 613414 files and directories currently
installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libx265-102_2.2-1~16.04.york0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libx265-102:amd64 (2.2-1~16.04.york0) ...

dpkg: error processing archive
/var/cache/apt/archives/libx265-102_2.2-1~16.04.york0_amd64.deb
(--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so.102', which
is also in package libx265-95:amd64 2.2-0~16.04.york0

dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib/libVLCQtWidgets.so.1.1 is not a
symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib/libVLCQtCore.so.1.1 is not a
symbolic link

Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libx265-102_2.2-1~16.04.york0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried so many things like autoclean, autoremove, remove libx265-102, remove libx265*, I also try to use --force-overright but I cannot get how to use it with apt-get.. give me some solution please...

Comment: For output, please use the `{}` button in the editor instead of the `"` button.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex : Sorry for wrong format, next time take care of these things.

Comment: Try `sudo apt clean`

Comment: sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libx265-102_2.2-1~16.04.york0_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I just install latest ffmpeg, then `sudo apt-get install -f` and problem solved. Thanks all.